# How can I define an interface method whose different implementation can return <T>, List<T>, List<List<T>> where T is a custom class

Tags: c#

```
interface IParser
{
     return type parseData(list<byte> data);
}
```

Where return type can be a `T`, `List<T>` or `List<List<T>>`

Comment: What about using ```object```?

Comment: All of these fall under `T`, though, since `T` could be anything. You would have to check in your method what `T` actually is. `IEnumerable<T>` would be more appropriate if you can at least guarantee it's always a sequence of some sort, even if possibly a nested one. If you really have only three specific types, make three differently-named methods (overloading on return type is not supported in C#).

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem, if the answers didn't help, edit your question to clarify your problems.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your interface like this

```
interface IParser<T>
{
    T ParseData(List<byte> data);
}
```

Can be used like this:

```
public class Parser<T> : IParser<T>
{
    public virtual T ParseData(List<byte> data) //virtual is optional
    {
        //do stuff and return T
        //T could be anything, a List, a struct, a class what ever
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

If you need a specific parser you could do this:

```
public class StringParser : Parser<string>
{
    public override string ParseData(List<byte> data)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Or if you need a specific parser for a collection of `T`

```
public class CollectionParser<TItem> : Parser<IEnumerable<TItem>>
{
    public override IEnumerable<TItem> ParseData(List<byte> data)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<TItem>;
    }
}
```

Comment: For completeness I'd suggest you also offer `interface IParser { T ParseData<T>(List<byte> data); }` as a choice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
public interface IParser<TOut> where TOut : class
{
    TOut ParseData(List<byte> data);
}
```

## edit

Since the question was about T as a custom class thereby verify that the type of TOut is class. Maybe a good addition would be as following:

```
public interface IParser<in TIn, out TOut> where TOut : class
{
    TOut ParseData(TIn data);
}
```

and the implementation would be:

```
class Parser : IParser<List<byte>, CustomClass>
{
    CustomClass ParseData(List<byte> data)
    {
     return new CustomClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest a constraint `TOut : class` then please explain why and how it benefits the OP.